Best practice for routinely importing content via a Rest API?
In the past I've used Feeds to import content. I have a new D10 project I'm working on and I'll need to regularly pull data from Pure API. The import will create new nodes with mapped fields of a custom content type. It only needs to be a downstream connection.
What is considered "best practice" to import data from a  REST API?

I would write a Migration definition, then set a scheduled job to call it via Drush.
